# Array Pointer compile time warning : warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Using a simple sample that involves an array point generates the following warnings. The code codes compile and execute which also leads to questions.

This is the int Array. 
        int numbers[3] = { 101, 202, 303};

These 2 calls generate the warnings.

```
    int *p2 = &numbers;
    int **p3 = &numbers;
```

The following are the Warning generated.

```
 > cc -o myApp test.c
 test.c: In function 'main':
 test.c:9:12: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 int *p2 = &numbers;
        ^
 test.c:10:13: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 int **p3 = &numbers;
         ^
```

The code used is the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int numbers[3] = { 101, 202, 303};
    int size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof (numbers[0]);

    int *p = numbers;
    int *p2 = &numbers;
    int **p3 = &numbers;
    int *p4 = &numbers[0];

    int *end = p + size;

    printf("p           = 0x%d\n", p);
    printf("p2          = 0x%d\n", p2);
    printf("p3          = 0x%d\n", p3);
    printf("numbers     = 0x%d\n", numbers);
    printf("&numbers    = 0x%d\n", &numbers);
    printf("numbers[0]  = 0x%d\n", numbers[0]);
    printf("&numbers[0] = 0x%d\n", &numbers[0]);

    for (; p != end; p++)
    {
            printf ("0x%d\n", p);
    }
}
```

When executed, here is the output.

```
> ./runTest
p           = 0x-207214704
p2          = 0x-207214704
p3          = 0x-207214704
numbers     = 0x-207214704
&numbers    = 0x-207214704
numbers[0]  = 0x101
&numbers[0] = 0x-207214704
0x-207214704
0x-207214700
0x-207214696
```

Both p2 and p3 as well as p all point to the same address. 
I really thought using p3 as a double pointer would have resolved the Warning, but it appears not. 
Why does p2 and p3 generate the Warnings and what is it trying to say?

Comment: A double pointer wouldn't have resolved the warning because `&numbers` is of type `int (*)[3]`, which is not the same as `int **`.

Comment: Also, to print a pointer value (of pointer to object type, not function type), use the `%p` format specifier and cast the pointer to type `void *` (or a qualified version of `void *`), e.g. `printf("p = %p\n", (void *)p);`. (Your implementation of C might also allow you to cast function pointers to `void *` and might also work with the `%p` format specifier without casting at all, but all that is non-standard.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the point which causes you this confusion. You first saw

```
 int *p = numbers;
```

Well don't think that `numbers` is of type pointer. It is simply an array object (`int[3]`) which is converted into pointer to first element of it - that is `int*`. This is known as array decaying.

Now you think in `int **p3 = &numbers;`- `&numbers` will be of type `int**`.

Well this is where the trick is - array decaying doesn't occure in some cases - when array is used as an operand to `&` operator - then it is one case like this - so it won't decay. It will be an array object whose pointer is considered which is `int(*)[3]` in this case.

With this logic `int *p2=&numbers` will also be something of which compiler will complain. The correct would be what is said here `int (*pp)[3] = &numbers`. Note that print the pointers(not a function pointer) use `%p` format specifier with the argument cast to `void*`.

The compiler tried to warn you about the pointer type mismatch. (For pointers the type to which it points to is of importance because of the pointer arithmetic is dictated by that).

From  §[6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, *an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.*

Answer (score 2):

First, always use `%p` to print pointer values:

```
printf( "%p\n", (void *) p );
printf( "%p\n", (void *) p1 );
```

Given the declaration

```
int numbers[3];
```

then the following are true:

```
Expression        Type        "Decays" to         Value
----------        ----        -----------         -----
   numbers        int [3]     int *               Address of first element of array
  &numbers        int (*)[3]  n/a                 Address of array (which is the same as above)
  *numbers        int         n/a                 Value of numbers[0]
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  Thus, under most circumstances (such as when it's the RHS of an assignment, or a parameter to a function), the expression `numbers` will have type `int *`.

So how do you properly initialize `p2` and `p3`?  That depends on what you want to happen when you write `p2 + 1` or `p2[1]` and `p3 + 1` or `p3[1]`.  If you want `p2 + 1` to point to the second element in `numbers`, or if you want `p2[1]` to be equal to `numbers[1]`, then you'd write

```
int *p2 = numbers;
```

If you want `p2 + 1` to point to the *next 3-element array of `int`* following the end of the `numbers` array, then you'd write

```
int (*p2)[3] = &numbers;
```

Then you'd initialize `p3` as

```
int **p3 = &p2;
```

or

```
int (**p3)[3] = &p2;
```

based on how `p2` was declared.

A picture might help.  Assume the following declarations:

```
int numbers[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };
int *p0 = numbers;
int (*p1)[3] = &numbers;
```

then things look something like this:

```
         +---+                    
numbers: | 0 | numbers[0] <------ p0, p1
         +---+                    
         | 1 | numbers[1] <------ p0 + 1
         +---+
         | 2 | numbers[2]
         +---+
          ...             <------ p1 + 1
```

Remember that with pointer arithmetic, `p + 1` points to the next object of the pointed-to type; if `p` points to an object that's 4 bytes wide, then `p + 1` points to the object starting 4 bytes after `p`.  If `p` points to an object that's 32 bytes wide (such as a small array), then `p + 1` points to the object starting 32 bytes after `p`.

Answer (score 1):

It should have been

```
int numbers[3] = { 101, 202, 303};
```

and

```
int (*p2)[3] = &numbers; // Here p2 is a pointer to an array of 3 members
```

The members should be accessed like

```
(*p2)[0],(*p2)[1] and (*p2)[2]
```

which is eqivalent to

```
*(*(p2)+0),*(*(p2)+1) and *(*(p2)+2)
```

and also to

```
p2[0][0],p2[0][1] and p2[0][2] // Since array notation can be used to dereference pointers.
```